# What to backup before messing with X

Tags: fedora, xorg, configuration, backup, etc

I haven't had need to mess with X for a long time (I'd guess it was still when Xfree86 ruled).
A few weeks ago, however, I was trying to get a laptop to use an external display and I managed to cripple the setup (annoying flashing screen).

Since the laptop was already due an upgrade (and I had a backup of `/home`) I just upgraded to F24 and moved on, but it got me thinking that I should probably have a backup of a working configuration.

**What files should I backup in case I need to mess with X again?**

Or should I just backup everything in `/etc` and not worry about specifics?

Comment: For pete's sake, back up your machine. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just back up `/etc`. (And don't put configuration files elsewhere, obviously, e.g. never modify files under `/usr`.)

Rather than rolling your own, install [etckeeper](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/etckeeper), which automatically commits modification in your chosen version control system on package upgrades. When you make changes, commit them (`git commit` or `hg commit` or `bzr commit` or `darcs record`) with an explicit log message to remember why you did it.